# how to download and display an image from an URL in R? And Rename ((Whole)

Tags: python, r, web-scraping

The file I attach there are a link and Name column. I wanted to download a file and give the name the same time. How could I do that on R. All of the links and names are sequential

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx6WF.jpg)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/qoyk9y

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Here's a guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please add your image as formatted text.